# Additional information: OpenCV: Different sizes of objects using c#

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

Currently, I am facing problem with my EmguCV c# code. I am trying to recognize my images from the database, but its not working. Once my face is detected, its crashing and then this error shows up

> Additional information: OpenCV: Different sizes of objects.

I tried searching for this error but I am clueless.

This is my code:

```
//Action for each element detected
foreach (MCvAvgComp f in facesDetected[0])
{
   t = t + 1;
   result = currentFrame.Copy(f.rect).Convert<Gray, byte>().Resize(100, 100, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.INTER.CV_INTER_CUBIC);
   //draw the face detected in the 0th (gray) channel with blue color
   currentFrame.Draw(f.rect, new Bgr(Color.Green), 2);

   //Database select the image row and pass to the eigenobjectrecognizer

   //ConnectToDatabase();
   if (Connection.State.Equals(ConnectionState.Open))
   {
      Connection.Close();
      TSTable.Clear();
      ConnectToDatabase();
   }
   //Connection.Open();
   OleDbCommand OledbSelect = new OleDbCommand("Select FaceName, FaceImage From TrainingSet1",Connection);
   OleDbDataReader reader = OledbSelect.ExecuteReader();

   while (reader.Read())
   {
      labels.Add(reader.GetValue(1).ToString()); 
      trainingImages.Add(gray);
   }

   if (TSTable.Rows.Count != 0)
   {
      //TermCriteria for face recognition with numbers of trained images like maxIteration
      MCvTermCriteria termCrit = new MCvTermCriteria(ContTrain, 0.001);

      //Eigen face recognizer
      EigenObjectRecognizer recognizer = new EigenObjectRecognizer(
                trainingImages.ToArray(), //database faceimage list
                labels.ToArray(), //facename list
                3000,
                ref termCrit);

      name = recognizer.Recognize(result);

      //Draw the label for each face detected and recognized
      currentFrame.Draw(name, ref font, new Point(f.rect.X - 2, f.rect.Y - 2), new Bgr(Color.LightGreen));

   }
```

I currently still new to EmguCV and C#. So some of the exceptions I don't understand. Can anyone help me with this.

And once the code breaks, it goes to the `EigenObjectRecognizer.cs`. This is the code where it breaks:

```
 public static float[] EigenDecomposite(Image<Gray, Byte> src, Image<Gray, Single>[] eigenImages, Image<Gray, Single> avg)
  {
     return CvInvoke.cvEigenDecomposite(
         src.Ptr,
         Array.ConvertAll<Image<Gray, Single>, IntPtr>(eigenImages, delegate(Image<Gray, Single> img) { return img.Ptr; }),
         avg.Ptr);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess, problem is in `trainingImages`. The width and height of each eigenImages must be the same as the width and height of the input image.

Your result image has size 100x100. So, all your `trainingImage` should have same size. Resize them, before adding to your list.

I review your code. Trouble still in sizes.
Line 305 replace to :

```
result = currentFrame.Copy(f.rect).Convert<Gray, byte>().Resize(gray.Width, gray.Height, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.INTER.CV_INTER_CUBIC);
```

Comment: Or is it because of this line code `trainingImages.Add(gray);`

Comment: I don't know where did you take `gray` variable. But you should resize this images to same size as your `result` image. Updated answer.

Comment: maybe you want to take a look at [this](http://pastebin.com/p1EsYREZ) . i really appreciate your help...

Comment: Update my answer. Check it please.

Comment: Problem still in sizes :) Updated answer, check it.

Comment: well now its working but why once i recognize the face, the fps is too slow. and my face name is showing system.byte[]...

Comment: So, you understood problem? Source image  and eigen images MUST be same size. About next - I guess you it's the another question and you should ask it as new question.