# Change code that looks for image in the txt file for the database

Tags: c#

I am creating a facial identification application, I found an example called MultiFaceRec, but this one is searching for the images that are saved in a folder with a numbering in bmp format and the names of the people that are a txt file saved in the sequences with the numbering of the image.

```
    #region Searching for txt file

    //Load of previus trainned faces and labels for each image
    string Labelsinfo = File.ReadAllText(Application.StartupPath + "/TrainedFaces/TrainedLabels.txt");
    string[] Labels = Labelsinfo.Split('%');
    NumLabels = Convert.ToInt16(Labels[0]);
    ContTrain = NumLabels;
    string LoadFaces;

    for (int tf = 1; tf < NumLabels + 1; tf++)
    {
        LoadFaces = "face" + tf + ".bmp";
        trainingImages.Add(new Image<Gray, byte>(Application.StartupPath + "/TrainedFaces/" + LoadFaces));
        labels.Add(Labels[tf]);
    }

    #endregion
```

I'm trying to change this by looking directly at the database, where I have an image field and a field with the person's name.

```
SqlConnection conConexao = clsdb.AbreBanco();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select fotografia, nome from pessoa  where fotografia is not null", conConexao);
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (dr.HasRows == true)
            {
                while (dr.Read())
                {

                    byte[] imageSource = (byte[])dr["fotografia"];
                    Bitmap image;

                    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(imageSource))
                    {
                        image = new Bitmap(stream);
                    }



                    trainingImages.Add(new Image<Gray, byte>(image));
                    labels.Add(dr["Nome"].ToString());
             }            
       }
```

But I'm getting an error in the class in this method:

```
#region static methods
      /// <summary>
      /// Caculate the eigen images for the specific traning image
      /// </summary>
      /// <param name="trainingImages">The images used for training </param>
      /// <param name="termCrit">The criteria for tranning</param>
      /// <param name="eigenImages">The resulting eigen images</param>
      /// <param name="avg">The resulting average image</param>
      public static void CalcEigenObjects(Image<Gray, Byte>[] trainingImages, ref MCvTermCriteria termCrit, out Image<Gray, Single>[] eigenImages, out Image<Gray, Single> avg)
      {
         int width = trainingImages[0].Width;
         int height = trainingImages[0].Height;

         IntPtr[] inObjs = Array.ConvertAll<Image<Gray, Byte>, IntPtr>(trainingImages, delegate(Image<Gray, Byte> img) { return img.Ptr; });

         if (termCrit.max_iter <= 0 || termCrit.max_iter > trainingImages.Length)
            termCrit.max_iter = trainingImages.Length;

         int maxEigenObjs = termCrit.max_iter;

         #region initialize eigen images
         eigenImages = new Image<Gray, float>[maxEigenObjs];
         for (int i = 0; i < eigenImages.Length; i++)
            eigenImages[i] = new Image<Gray, float>(width, height);
         IntPtr[] eigObjs = Array.ConvertAll<Image<Gray, Single>, IntPtr>(eigenImages, delegate(Image<Gray, Single> img) { return img.Ptr; });
         #endregion

         avg = new Image<Gray, Single>(width, height);

         CvInvoke.cvCalcEigenObjects(
             inObjs,
             ref termCrit,
             eigObjs,
             null,
             avg.Ptr);
      }
```

The error is:
**Emgu.CV.Util.CvException: 'OpenCV: Different sizes of objects'**

How to solve this at the time of searching the image in the database?

Comment: I think you need to look at the stacktrace. What research have you done? Have you tried debugging your own code? For example: https://stackoverflow.com/q/31918751/1531971 (among others)

Comment: @jdv Hello, I have seen this answer, my problem is similar, but I do not know if it was very clear in my question my doubt is how to pass the size to the image within the select I made and I posted the question. thank you

Comment: Then you need to tell us in the question you did this research and why that solution does not help you.